# Can thinking-sphinx ransack work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, ransack

Our project is using Ransack at the moment, we are thinking to introduce Thinking-Sphinx. However they both use search keyword. Is any way to use Thinking-Sphinx and Ransack in a same project?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ransack's search method is just an alias. You can use the `ransack` method instead.

Instead of:

```
@q = Person.search(params[:q])
@people = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

Use:

```
@q = Person.ransack(params[:q])
@people = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

Person.search should call ThinkingSphinx as usual.

Comment: But what if I`m using it in a single form - so that i would like to have search quiery be separated form ransack params? Should i employ custom params processing or digg into ransack code?